# How can i fix my 2d array error in netbeans 2.8

Tags: java, arrays

What do you think is the problem with this? Whenever I input 2D arrays, I always encounter this.

> incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int[][]
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - array dimension missing

My code is:

```
int [][]array= new int[][];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted is invalid Java syntax, hence the error message.

Either only declare a variable:

```
int[][] array;
```

Or also initialize it, but then give a proper size:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][3]; // 5 rows, 3 columns
// or
int[][] array = new int[5][]; // 5 rows, inner arrays are null
// or
int[][] array = { { 1, 8, 10 }, { -5, 3 }, { 0 } }; // values directly given
```

In Java, arrays are **fixed-size** data-structures. So at the moment you create them, you have to tell them their size one way or another.

If you pay close attention, all of the above ways either explicitly or implicitly declare the size of the array.

Comment: Why the downvote? Id like to improve my answer. Or is it just because of _"answering a bad question"_? If so, note the meta-topic on "_Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?_" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions And also note that the question has a good vote-ratio and no close votes yet.